# Getting Worksheets renamed in excel after importing data from the web

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to download the daily prices of our stock exchange using the following code in vba. Although the code works i cant seem to be able to get the sheets renamed to the corresponding day when the price list was obtained.

```
Dim DownloadDay As Date

DownloadDay = #3/4/2014#

Do While DownloadDay < #4/4/2014#

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

 Call website(Format(DownloadDay, "YYYYMMDD"))

'INCREMENT THE DAY

Sheets.Add.Name = "DownloadDay"

DownloadDay = DownloadDay + 1



  Loop

 End Sub

 Sub website(sDate As String)

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
 "URL;http://live.mystocks.co.ke/price_list/" & DownloadDay & "/", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))


.Name = DownloadDay
'To rename each work sheet with the corresponding day'


.FieldNames = True

.RowNumbers = False

.FillAdjacentFormulas = False

.PreserveFormatting = True

.RefreshOnFileOpen = False

.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


 End With

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of VBA will set the name of your worksheet:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "NewName"
```

You can not use "/" the character in the name though, and the variable is set to a date not a string.

Try this.

```
.name = CSTR(FORMAT(DownloadDay,"YYYYMMMDD"))
```